# Transfer Township game progress from iPhone to Android device

Tags: sync, data-transfer

I have Samsung Galaxy S3. I've been playing Township on my iPhone for awhile. When I bought the tablet, I can't get it to sync.

I've downloaded Township, but it's starting from scratch and I'm on level 50 something on iPhone and don't want to start all over.

Is there something I can do for that?

Comment: What kind of tablet? Does either app have some kind of account that you need to sign into that could be used to sync data? The games would likely need to facilitate the syncing themselves - Android and iOS are not really intercompatible like that.

Answer (score -1):

http://support.playrix.com/hc/en-us/articles/213578197-How-do-I-transfer-my-game-progress-from-1-device-to-another-

this worked on my phone. From iPhone to ASUS :)

Comment: Link-only answers can become useless if the link goes dead, so it would be extra helpful if you can [edit] your answer and include a summary of the steps.

Comment: You should quote this from your link: "*NOTE: For more information on how to transfer your game progress from iOS to Android (or visa versa) please contact our Support Team.*"